# Class objects not declared in scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am currently experiencing a problem that I just can't seem to wrap my head around why it would be occurring.
In my (Unsplit)program I've created a class that defines an entity object and is able to handle its creation and variables just fine (as I've tested before adding

```
std::string getName(Entity)const;
std::string getType(Entity)const;
int getDamage(Entity)const;
int getHealth(Entity)const;
```

But when I do... Even though they are already declared publicly in the class and I am fully able to call Initialize(); Attack(); and PrintStats(); just fine, it doesn't see the other four and therefor are not able to be called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
using namespace std;

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity() { // default constructor

        name = "Human";
        type = "Normal";
        damage = 1;
        health = 100;

    }
    void printStats();
    void Initialize(string, string, int, int); //transformer or setting function
    void Attack(Entity&); //observer or getter function
    std::string getName(Entity)const;
    std::string getType(Entity)const;
    int getDamage(Entity)const;
    int getHealth(Entity)const;

private://data members and special function prototypes
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
    int damage;
    int health;

};

void summonEnemy(Entity&);

int main () {

    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand (time(NULL));

    Entity  Player;//declaring new class objects
    Entity  Enemy;//declaring new class objects
    Player.Initialize("Player", "Normal", 10, 90);
    summonEnemy(Enemy);

    return 0;

}

void summonEnemy(Entity &target) {

    target.Initialize("Enemy", "Normal", floor(rand() % 20 + 1), floor(rand() % 100));
   cout << "An " << getType(target) << " type " << getName(target) << " has appeared with " <<
        getHealth(target) << "HP and can do " << getDamage(target) << " damage.";

}
```

Error message:

```
error:'getType' Was not defined in this scope.
error:'getName' Was not defined in this scope.
error:'getHealth' Was not defined in this scope.
error:'getDamage' Was not defined in this scope.
```

Cut off some code to narrow it down such that only what could be the cause of the problem is showing... But honestly its probably something simple that I am not seeing. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling them correctly.  They are members of the `Entity` class, not standalone functions.  Remove the `Entity` parameters from them, as they already have an implicit `Entity *this` parameter, and then call them like this:

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(); // default constructor
    ...
    std::string getName() const;
    std::string getType() const;
    int getDamage() const;
    int getHealth() const;
    ...
};
```

```
Entity::Entity()
{
    Initialize("Human", "Normal", 1, 100);
}

std::string Entity::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

std::string Entity::getType() const
{
    return type;
}

int getDamage() const
{
    return damage;
}

int getHealth() const
{
    return health;    
}
```

```
void summonEnemy(Entity &target)
{
    target.Initialize("Enemy", "Normal", floor(rand() % 20 + 1), floor(rand() % 100));
    cout << "An " << target.getType() << " type " << target.getName() << " has appeared with " <<
        target.getHealth() << "HP and can do " << target.getDamage() << " damage.";
}
```

Comment: I have edited it as such and it has stopped complaining about them not being declared but rather now is telling me that there is no matching function

**error: no matching function for call to 'Entity::getType()'**

Answer (score 2):

`getType` is a member function of `Entity`, so you need to call it on an `Entity` object:

```
target.getType();
```

In the class, you could implement it as:

```
class Entity {
    ...
    std::string getType() const { return type; }
    ...
};
```

The same is true for your other three setters.